# Jersey 1.0 JAX RS: How to transform uri string paths into REST method calls?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

I'm fairly new to Jersey JAX-RS, so please bear with me. We're trying to add batch processing capabilities to our REST API by having the client submit a JSON list of uri paths that it would typically have made individually. For example:

```
[{"/rest/shoes/1"} , {"/rest/shirts/24"} , {"/rest/costume?color=green"}]
```

Again, each string in this list would be paths (or subpaths) in the REST api. 
This list would be submitted to a single path, say "/rest/queries", which would correspond to a method `public List<Response> queries(List<String>)` . The idea is to execute the corresponding methods for each path in the list given. Is there a way to do that on Jersey 1.0 JAX-RS? Or, alternatively, is there a way to configure JAX-RS that it would just automatically do batch GET requests?

Our goal is to have the batch request that contain several GET requests that can be entirely different from each other, similar to my example above.